# Fixed point in a map of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ and $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [a,b]$ be a monotone increasing function. Assume that $a<f(a)$ and $b>f(b)$. Show that there exists $x^*$ such that $f(x^*)=x^*$.

Here is what I did:

$$\sup {\{x\in [a,b]:f(x) \geq x\}} = \inf \{x\in [a,b]:f(x)\leq x\}=x^*$$
$$\implies x^*\leq f(x^*)\leq x^*$$
$$\implies f(x^*)=x^*$$
By the squeezing theorem

Is this correct or too hand-wavey?

Comment: how could you prove that $$\sup {\{x\in [a,b]:f(x) \geq x\}} = \inf \{x\in [a,b]:f(x)\leq x\}=x^*?$$

Comment: Can it be something like this?: $\exists c,d\in (a,b)$ such that $\sup\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)\geq x\}=c$ and $\inf\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)\leq x\}=d$ $\implies a\leq f(a),...,c\leq f(c),d\geq f(d),...,b\geq f(b)$ $\implies c \leq f(c)\leq f(d)\leq d$. So for some $c$, $c=d$ and viceversa. Hence sup=inf of those sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we know $f(x)\in [a,b] \ \forall x\in [a,b]$

and $$g(a)\geq a \implies g(a)-a\geq 0$$
and also $$g(b)\leq b \implies g(b)-b\leq0$$
We know, by the Intermediate Value Thereom $$\exists \ x^* \in [a,b] \ni g(x^*)-x^*=0$$
That is$$g(x^*)=x^*$$
So we know that there must be a fixed point in $[a,b]$.

Comment: But is mine correct?

Comment: @George You cannot implicitly assume that $\sup = \inf$, since these may very well be different values.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work according your comment.

You can only have $c\le f(c)\le f(d) \le d$ at most, however, you can not conclude that $c=d$.

Comment: But you can conlude that there exists some c such that c=d? If not, how would I improve it?

Comment: No, you can not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of a good idea that does not work for technical reasons. Always keep an eye for these because this is the stuff counterexamples are made of.

If $f(x)=x$, the sup is $b$, while the inf is $a$. More generally, if $f$ happens to have more than one fixed point, then $\sup > \inf$, and your argument does not work.

Comment: Can I then say that $\exists c\in [a,b]$ such that $\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)\geq x\}\cap \{x\in[a,b]:f(x)\leq x\} =c$ $\implies c\leq f(c)$ and $c\geq f(c)$ $\implies f(c)=c$